# How to delete all contents of a folder with Ruby-Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `public/cache` folder which has files and folders. How can I completely empty that folder using a rake task?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Ruby has the *nix `rm -rf` equivalent in the [FileUtils](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) module that you can use to delete both files and non-empty folders/directories:

```
FileUtils.rm_rf('dir/to/remove')
```

To keep the directory itself and only remove its contents:

```
FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob('dir/to/remove/*'))

FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir['dir/to/remove/*'])      # shorter version of above
```

Comment: That would remove the folder itself as well -- is there anyway to have it only remove the contents of that folder, but keep the empty folder?

Comment: Found it.. `FileUtils.mkdir`. Thanks

Comment: For folder contents only: FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob('dir/*')) (please note the asterisk in the end)

Comment: About `FileUtils.rm_fr`: A directory that is called _public/cache_ is probably world writable. In this case, using `FileUtils.rm_rf` there is prone to TOCTTOU problems: Someone else could do tricks with symlinks during the runtime of your `rm_rf`. You might be better off with [FileUtils.remove_entry_secure](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-remove_entry_secure)

Comment: The suggested commands with `Dir.glob` will _not_ remove files or directories in _dir/to/remove_ that have a name that starts with a dot. For example, _dir/to/remove/.config/_ will not be removed. You should use `File::FNM_DOTMATCH` and then handle `.` and `..`: `Dir.glob('*', File::FNM_DOTMATCH).select {|d| not ['.','..'].include? d}`

Comment: You could use `Dir[...]` instead of `Dir.glob(...)` to make code even more shorter and simplier

Answer (score 3):

You can run arbitrary commands using backticks like so:

```
`rm -fr public/cache/*`
```

This may be more platform-dependent than what you want, but it opens up a lot of possibilities.

Comment: That's called a backtick.

Answer (score 3):

Great answers here already. You might also be interested to know that Rails 5 has a rake task to do this built-in:

```
rake tmp:cache:clear # Clear cache files from tmp/
```